# How to get to Release web.config file

Tags: asp.net

How do I get to release web.config ?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I cannot seem to find how to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your web.config file, click "add config transforms" to create the configuration transformations for each of your solution configuration.

Then to preview the files, right click on it (ie: web.release.config) and select "preview transform".

**Note**: if you do not have the mentionned options in the context menu, consider installing the "Web essentials" extention. It will make your life easier and save a leprauchaun from a terrible death.

Comment: Thanks. but add config transforms is disabled on my machine.

Comment: Then the configuration are already created. Try activating the "show all files" option at the top of the solution explorer. Then see if there is an expand button (the "triangle" thingy) next to your web.config. If there is one, expand it, and right click on a file to preview the transform.